# How to run two DE's on one partition

Tags: gnome, kde, desktop-environments

How to segregate 2 desktop editions (kde/gnome) installed on one partition using kdm/gdm to start, doesn't matter which. But not share the apps, bins or libs.

I don't want the mish-mush of Gnome and KDE colliding and I don't want to dual boot.
or is there a way to adjust for the app-crowding that is expected.

The `/home` MUST be the only shared folder of the system.

Is this too far fetched?

Comment: Have you seen http://askubuntu.com/questions/219911/how-to-completely-separate-desktop-enviroments/?

Comment: I would experiment with creating two `chroot`-ed environments where you install different sets of packages and then run two copies of X each with its own login manager... I anticipate there may be some problems which will render the idea stupid, but that would be an interesting experiment.

Comment: @Sergey the suggestion failed. The answer must be NO!

Comment: @Ringtail: provided that Linux is open source, there's absolutely nothing you can't do with it - the only question is the amount of effort required to achieve what you want. Have a look at Android :) So the question may be "yes, but that would require a custom X driver", or "yes, but that would require a custom kernel module" (both of which are very unlikely, btw), but never a NO :)